# Angular 5: token is not able to authenticate API call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, angular5

I have a simple API application protected with Azure AD, implicit flow is true.

Now Angular 5 application using `ADAL` library, implicit flow is true, I m getting token.

But the same token when I am using to call a API, it's not authorize.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Adal5Service } from 'adal-angular5';
import { adal } from 'adal-angular';


const config: adal.Config = {                           
  tenant: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',                      
  clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'    
}                                                       


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private service: Adal5Service) {      
    this.service.init(config);                      
  }    
  ngOnInit(){
    // Handle callback if this is a redirect from Azure
    this.service.handleWindowCallback();

    // Check if the user is authenticated. If not, call the login() method
    if (!this.service.userInfo.authenticated) {
      this.service.login();
    }

    // Log the user information to the console
    console.log('username ' + this.service.userInfo.username);

    console.log('authenticated: ' + this.service.userInfo.authenticated);

    console.log('name: ' + this.service.userInfo.profile.name);

    console.log('token: ' + this.service.userInfo.token);

    console.log(this.service.userInfo.profile);
  }

  // Logout Method
  public logout() {
    this.service.logOut();
  }
}
```

Both Web API and Angular 5 application registers with Azure AD and necessary permission given.

Any suggestion, why token will not validate?

Comment: I have used ADAL. Try to downgrade and test ADAL package

Comment: from where what I need to download?

Comment: I'm not sure but downgrading adal-angular package by npm install @adal-angular@<specifit-version> might help. And also check your site address registered in azure settings double check your local server does support token authentication or not.

Comment: Check the token that is being sent with the request. You can decode it with https://jwt.ms. Especially important is the `aud` claim. That should match to your API's client id or App ID URI.